# trigger() and triggerHandler() with 'click', trigger thickbox on page load

Tags: jquery, thickbox

im trying to trigger a click event on a link on the page load. im currently working on this code here http://jsfiddle.net/QPPbA/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#trigger-me').trigger('click'); 
});

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" id="trigger-me">trigger hidden</a>
```

but it does not work. what im i missing here?

**EDIT**

I would like to trigger a thickbox on page load, i got some code but it only shows the black "tint".. so i thougth i would trigger it like this but this way does not work either.. any suggestions?

Comment: You need to say what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't got a click event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger-me').click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
    $('#trigger-me').trigger('click'); 
});
```

update: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPPbA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.location = $('#trigger-me').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger an event with JavaScript, the browser's default action for that event isn't invoked.  In this case, it won't cause a navigation when you trigger the `click` event on a link.

If you want to redirect the visitor to another page, you can use `window.location`:

```
window.location = $("#trigger-me").prop("href");
```